# Riemann-Hurwitz formula $\chi(X)=d(F)\cdot\chi(Y)-R_F$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I read the book of Miranda on Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces, I read the proof of Riemann-Hurwitz formula page 52-53. I mean for holomorphic map $F:X\to Y$ between Riemann Surfaces, we have $$\chi(X)=d(F)\cdot\chi(Y)-R_F$$ with $\chi(X)$ is the Euler characteristic and $d(F)$ is the degree of $F$ and $R_F=\sum_{p \in X} (e_p(F)-1)$.

This result is proved in three steps:

First, we prove the set of ramification points is finite (easy), so $R_F$ is a finite sum. And we take a triangulation of $Y$, such that each branch point of $F$ is a vertex. I don't understand this, is this because any triangle is triangulated? I want to prove it formally.

Step 2: Assume there are $v_Y$ vertices, $e_Y$ edges, and $t_Y$ triangles. Lift this triangulation to $X$ via the map $F$ (how we can do it?), and there are $v_X$ (resp. $e_X , t_X$) vertices (resp. edges, triangles) on $X$. Since there are no ramification points over the general point of any triangle, each triangle of $Y$ lift to $\deg(F)$ triangle in $X$ (why, really two days to understand that and I can't). Thus $t_X = t_Y . d(F)$ Similarly $e_X =e_Y .d(F)$. Now fix a vertex $q\in Y$. The number of preimages of $q$ in $X$ is $F^{-1}(q)$, which we can rewrite $$|F^{-1}(q)|=d(F)+\sum_{p\in F^{-1}(q)}1-e_p (F).$$ Therefore the total number of preimages of vertices of $Y$, which is the number $v_X$ is $$v_X = \sum_{vertex \ q \ of \ Y}(d(F)+\sum_{p\in F^{-1}(q)}1-e_p (F))=d(F)\cdot v_Y - \sum_{vertex \ q\ of \ Y}\sum_{p \in F^{-1}(q)}e_p(F)-1)\\ = d(F)\cdot v_Y - \sum_{vertex \ p \ of \ X}e_p(F)-1$$ Also, I think the last inequality is true because the set of vertex $p$ of $X$ is the set of preimages of $q$ vertex in $Y$. It's true?

Last step is to calculate $\chi(X)$, we have $$\chi(X)=v_X -e_X + t_X=d(F)v_Y - d(F) e_Y + d(F)\cdot t_Y-\sum_{p \ vertex \ of \ X}e_p (F)-1,$$ I think last inequality holding because every ramification point of $F$ is a vertex of $X$.

Comment: My advice is to try to come up with a simple example for a map $\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$ thought of as homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i don't come to the result.

Comment: First off, the Riemann-Hurwitz formula holds for *compact* Riemann surfaces. For instance, to see that the the set of ramification points is finite, you use that a closed and discrete subset of a *compact* space is finite. If you drop the compactness requirement, this need not be the case: Take a non-finite discrete closed set $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi\mathbb{Z}$.) Find a non-constant holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which posesses a primitive and whose zero set is $S$ (e.g. $\operatorname{cos}(z)$)…

Comment: … then its primitive (e.g. $\operatorname{sin}(z)$) has $S$ as its set of ram. points.

Comment: Miranda defines a *triangulation* of a compact $2$-manifold $M$ (possibly with boundary) as a decomposition of $M$ into closed subsets, each homeomorphic to a triangle, such that any two triangles are either disjoint, meet only at a single vertex or meet only along a single edge. In other words, a triangulation of $Y$ is made up of of a pair $(v_Y,e_Y)$, consisting of a set of one-element subsets of $Y$ (vertices $v_Y$) and another set of subsets of $Y$ (edges $e_Y$), satisfying certain properties.

Comment: Miranda now claims that, if every branch point of $F$ is in $v_Y$, then the pair $(F^{-1}(v_Y),F^{-1}(e_Y))$ gives a triangulation of $X$. To argue that every triangle in $Y$ "lifts" (if you take out branch points and ramification points, $F$ is a covering map. This explains the visual terminology.) to $\operatorname{deg}(F)$-many triangles in $X$, you can employ the Local Normal form of a non-constant holomorphic map.

Comment: If a triangle $T$ in $Y$ does not have a branch point as its vertex, then it "lifts" to $\operatorname{deg}(F)$-many triangles in $X$, since taking out ram. points and branch points makes it a of $\operatorname{deg}(F)$-sheeted topological covering map. If it contains precisely one branch point as a vertex, then the Local Normal Form establishes that $T$ lifts to $\operatorname{deg}(F)$-many triangles which all have one common vertex. If necessary, you have to refine the triangulation so that the triangle $T$ is a subset of the neighborhood obtained from the Local Normal form.

Comment: If the triangle has more than one branch point as its vertex, you can suitably refine the triangulation such that the new triangulation only contains triangles with only one branch point as their vertex.

Comment: Regarding your questions why the two equalities hold. For the first question note that $X=\coprod_{q\in Y}F^{-1}(q)$. The second one is obtained by collecting what you have obtained thus far in the proof.

Comment: Lastly, I agree with Alekos Robotis that working through the proof with a specific example $\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, e.g. $z\mapsto z^n$ for $n\geq 2$, is a good idea.

Comment: @M.C. if you're going to write this much, it should probably be an answer.